# How to integrate find-sec-bugs in spotbugs?

Tags: java, spotbugs, find-sec-bugs

Recently I downloaded the findsecbugs-plugin-1.11.0.jar in order to use it in spotbugs. I copied this jar file to the folder *plugin* of the project spotbugs(4.1.4).

I execute spotbugs making use of ant. When I run the ant target I get the following message:

```
 [spotbugs] Executing SpotBugs FindBugsTask from ant task
 [spotbugs] Running SpotBugs...
 [spotbugs] The following classes needed for analysis were missing:
 [spotbugs]   apply
 [spotbugs]   applyAsInt
 [spotbugs]   test
 [spotbugs]   accept
 [spotbugs] Java Result: 3
 [spotbugs] Classes needed for analysis were missing
```

Do you know what extra jar files do I need?

Comment: Have you considered using [Maven](https://maven.apache.org), or is there a particular reason for Ant?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to use ant.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the Ant integration does not have plugins configuration.

### Option 1 : Exec Task

You could run the command-line version of Find-Security-Bugs. You have to invoke the tool with `exec` task. With this, you will be able to generate XML, HTML and SARIF reports.

- [Download find-sec-bugs cli from release](https://github.com/find-sec-bugs/find-sec-bugs/releases/)
- [Exec task from Ant](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html)

### Option 2 : Java task

As an alternative, you can use the Java task to invoke the class `edu.umd.cs.findbugs.FindBugs2` which handles the CLI interface of SpotBugs.

You can take inspiration from the Maven implementation which use under the hood the AntRunner.

```
ant.java(classname: "edu.umd.cs.findbugs.FindBugs2", inputstring: getSpotbugsAuxClasspath(), fork: "${fork}", failonerror: "true", clonevm: "false", timeout: "${timeout}", maxmemory: "${maxHeap}m") {
...
}
```

I'm not 100% sure that you can define pluginArtifacts from an Ant script. You might have to create a small plugin to do it.

- Example of FindBugs2 invocation from Ant java task:
  [SpotBugsMojo.groovy](https://github.com/spotbugs/spotbugs-maven-plugin/blob/spotbugs/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/mojo/spotbugs/SpotBugsMojo.groovy#L1057)
- [Java task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html)

Answer (score 0):

Although not documented in https://spotbugs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ant.html#parameters, the Ant integration does support plugins using the pluginList parameter (see https://github.com/spotbugs/spotbugs/blob/master/spotbugs-ant/src/main/java/edu/umd/cs/findbugs/anttask/FindBugsTask.java). So,

```
<spotbugs home="..." ... 
          pluginList="findsecbugs-plugin-1.12.0.jar">
...
</spotbugs>
```

works.
Try running with parameter `debug="true"` to see details.